# How to pass argument to SQL query in Python and write result in csv file

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I am trying to pass a runtime argument to MYSQL query in Python script. I am using python 3.7.3.
I get an error with below code.

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line
```

I am trying to understand on how to pass the argument value to sql query.
Another issue is that the it does not write records to .csv file. It only creates the file and adds header to the file

Here is my sample code:

```
# File to store data from SQL
filePath = '/home/'
file = 'test.csv'



def main(account: str):

    # Staging Security
    cnxm = mysql.connector.connect(option_files='........)

    print('variable value is', account)

    # Cursor to execute query.
    cursor = cnxm.cursor()

    sqlSelect = """(Select * from AB where account = %s)"""


    # Execute query.
    cursor.execute(sqlSelect)

    myresult = cursor.fetchall()

    for x in myresult:
        print(x)

    print('Query ran successfully')

    # Fetch the data returned.
    results = cursor.fetchall()


    # Extract the table headers.
    #headers = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
    headers = ['uuid']


    # Open CSV file for writing.
    openfile = open(filePath + file, 'w')
    csvFile = csv.writer(openfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\r\n', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, escapechar='\\')

    # Add the headers and data to the CSV file.
    csvFile.writerow(headers)
    csvFile.writerows(results)



    #Close file
    openfile.close()

    #Close cursor
    cursor.close()

def run() -> str:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Account',
        usage='python test.py --account XYZ1234'
    )
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--account', required=True, type=str, dest='account', help='account info')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.account)
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(run())
```

I run my script using:
python3 test.py -a  ABC123XY

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are using string formatter in your sql query and you forgot to replace the placeholder with actual value. Correct query would be: `sqlSelect = """(Select * from AB where account = %s)"""%account`

Comment: Hi @BijayRegmi. Thanks for the quick reply. I added single quotes around '%s' and it worked.
= '%s')"""%account

Comment: I get the result printed from this on screen:
 for x in myresult:
        print(x)

Are you able help with the writing to csv part as well?